# Kafka : Cannot create embedded kafka server

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Update:

Here is the sample code I am trying to follow.

https://gist.github.com/asmaier/6465468

It should work with kafka 0.10.x

I am trying to create an embedded kafka server as

```
        EmbeddedZookeeper zkServer = new EmbeddedZookeeper();
        String zkConnect = ZKHOST + ":" + zkServer.port();
        ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(zkConnect, 30000, 30000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
        ZkUtils zkUtils = ZkUtils.apply(zkClient, false);

        // setup Broker
        Properties brokerProps = new Properties();
        brokerProps.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", zkConnect);
        brokerProps.setProperty("broker.id", "0");
        brokerProps.setProperty("log.dirs", Files.createTempDirectory("kafka-").toAbsolutePath().toString());
        brokerProps.setProperty("listeners", "PLAINTEXT://:" + BROKERPORT);
        brokerProps.setProperty("advertised.listeners", "PLAINTEXT://" + BROKERHOST +":" + BROKERPORT);
        //brokerProps.setProperty("security.inter.broker.protocol","PLAINTEXT");
        KafkaConfig config = new KafkaConfig(brokerProps);
        Time mock = new MockTime();
        KafkaServer kafkaServer = TestUtils.createServer(config, mock);
        logger.info("TestKafkaServer created");
```

but i get

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS
    at kafka.server.Defaults$.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:183)
    at kafka.server.Defaults$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at kafka.log.Defaults$.<init>(LogConfig.scala:35)
    at kafka.log.Defaults$.<clinit>(LogConfig.scala)
    at kafka.log.LogConfig$.<init>(LogConfig.scala:246)
    at kafka.log.LogConfig$.<clinit>(LogConfig.scala)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:270)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:795)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:797)
    at com.ibm.whi.bap.helper.test.kafka.KafkaServerTest.<init>(KafkaServerTest.java:56)
    at com.ibm.whi.bap.helper.test.kafka.KafkaTest.checkAllProperties(KafkaTest.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatchman$1.evaluate(TestWatchman.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.whi.bap.helper.test.kafka.KafkaTest.tearDown(KafkaTest.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:37)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatchman$1.evaluate(TestWatchman.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

at

```
KafkaConfig config = new KafkaConfig(brokerProps);
```

what am i doing wrong? I tried to play with

```
brokerProps.setProperty("security.inter.broker.protocol","PLAINTEXT");
```

but nothing worked. I just want to create an embedded kafka server for unit testing. I do not want to set up any sort of security at all.

here is my maven

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1.0</version>
            <classifier>test</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1.0</version>
            <classifier>test</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: maybe because kafka doesn't like arsenal fans. JK. You could try HDP's Sandbox, which natively deploys zookeeper and brokers. Only issue is opening ports (as it's a docker).

Comment: haha, no problem! i'm not a fan of kafka either :P the issue is that i want the embedded zookeeper as i have some unit tests. i dont need a kafka server outside of these tests. i know that the above code used to work for kafka 0.8 i think or maybe o.9 but now it does not work for 0.10. i am guessing ti has to do with some broker property not being set. any ideas?

Comment: Oh, there are a lot of changes between 0.8 and 0.10. For example, consumers now connect directly to brokers. Reading your code again, I think you are missing Scala package, did you try adding that dependency?

Comment: no i dont have that, what dependency is that?

Comment: please see the update i posted

Answer (score 2):

This is not an code issue. This is version mismatch. The library you are using(https://gist.github.com/asmaier/6465468) is compiled against Kafka 0.10.0.0 , which is different from the kafka version which you are using(). That is why it is not able to find the field **DEFAULT_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS** . You might want to take a look the below links:-

[embeeded zookeeper](https://github.com/diegoicosta/kafka-confluent-examples/blob/master/kafka-streams/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/zookeeper/ZooKeeperEmbedded.java)

[embedeed kafka](https://github.com/diegoicosta/kafka-confluent-examples/blob/master/kafka-streams/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/kafka/EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster.java)

You can just copy these to java classes into your project source/ or you can modify some details ( like removing schema registry). This will be simpler than depending on some library(as you are currently depending on https://gist.github.com/asmaier/6465468 ) ,just to create a in memory kafka cluster. After all this is just a few lines of code.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! i tried the above with kafka updated to 0.10.1.0 but i still get `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS` at `effectiveConfig.put(KafkaConfig$.MODULE$.BrokerIdProp(), 0);`

Comment: This error you are getting with https://gist.github.com/asmaier/6465468 or confluent solution?

Comment: with confluent. i tried using the https://github.com/diegoicosta/kafka-confluent-examples/blob/master/kafka-streams/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/kafka/KafkaEmbedded.java

Comment: the embedded zookeeper starts just fine

Comment: i am not even adding any properties, just trying to use the defauts

Comment: Can you please try this :   https://github.com/diegoicosta/kafka-confluent-examples/blob/master/kafka-streams/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/kafka/EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster.java

Comment: You just need to remove schema registry from code in above link. I have been using this and this is just working fine for me. Try modify. If does not work then please give your entire updated code with updated build file.

Comment: i'm afraid it did not work. i still get the same exception, now at 

`effectiveConfig.put(KafkaConfig$.MODULE$.ZkConnectProp(), zookeeper.connectString());`

Comment: seems like anytime we try to touch KafkaConfig$, the code crashes. how is it working for you? what does your maven pom look like?

Comment: Did you try without Kafkacinfig. You can directly put properties like: zookeeper.connect and broker.id for example

Comment: TestUtils.createServer needs the kafkaconfig object

Comment: i can create a new KafkaServer object without it